# SQL example: retrieve musicianID with no gigs played?

Tags: sql

Suppose you have two tables:

### Musicians

- musicianID (primary key, int)
- name (varchar)
- instrument (varchar)

### Gigs

- GigID (primary key, int)
- musicianID (foreign key from Musicians)
- location (varchar)

How would I retrieve the musicianIDs which have not played a gig i.e. that don't have a reference in the Gigs table?

Thanks!

Comment: A musician query with answers by George Martin, hmmmmm......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be more efficient than the query suggested by martin because it doesn't use a subquery:

```
select musicianID
from musicians m
left join gigs g on g.musicianId = m.musicianID
where g.musicianId is null
```

Comment: yeah, but it does a join.  I would check the query analyzer on the specific system to determine that :)

Comment: Certainly - I am positive that on mysql this would be more efficient for any non-trivial amount of data - subqueries being a bolted-on feature.

Comment: @Arthur Thomas: Joins are always quicker than sub-queries.  Most of the time a sub-query will be O(N1*N2) and join will be O(N1+N2) or O(max(N1,N2)) -- it is just like a nested loop.

Comment: @Hogan: A subquery is like a nested loop when it is a *correlated* subquery, but a simple subquery like `select ID from User where name = 'bobo'` is usually optimized by the compiler to only run once.

Comment: @OrbMan: Sure, could be true depending on the implementation -- Not the case here, the where statement in the sub-query used a value in the outer query.  No point in talking about edge cases when people are not grasping the basics.

Comment: thats cool.  I just mention that because I did an explain on some sample tables I made up and it came up with the same plan.  But of course my dataset was as small as it gets haha.

Comment: @Arthur Thomas -- hmmm... have to see the plan... maybe you had a typo in the `WHERE g.musicianID = m.musicianID` line?

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Musicians m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Gigs g
    WHERE g.musicianID = m.musicianID
)
```

Here's the (e.g.) MySQL documentation on [EXISTS and NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   M.*
FROM Musicians M
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Gigs G
      ON G.musicianId = M.musicianID
WHERE G.musicianId IS NULL
```